# Conflict for org.eclipse.ui.window.newEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Once I relaunch the RCP application I am getting this warning message (Error Log)-
Conflict for 'org.eclipse.ui.window.newEditor':HandlActivation...

as shown in the image-
[image]

What can be the reason of the same.

Answer (score 0):

are you using e4 or 3.*.
if you are using e4, can easily check conflict using application editor(SHIFT+ ALT + F9) window.